# Group columns with name

Tags: excel, vba

I realize I can group columns with VBA - which is very handy:

```
Columns("F:H").Group
```

When the group is closed, I cannot see what columns are grouped - and if I have multiple groups / "plus"-signs next to each other, it becomes even more confusing as I have to open all of them to find the correct group.

Is it possible to give a group a name with VBA?

[image]

Comment: `Columns("F:H").Name = "GroupName"` should do it for you.

Comment: fair point, this works so that the user can select the columns of a specific group when it is open - however, I am looking for a way to have the name appear above the grouping-area (even when it is closed) so the user can easily know which "plus"-sign to expand for the group he wants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS @kevin9999 in the comments suggested I solved it with `Columns("F:H").Name = "GroupName"` - I added an empty column between the groups with the preceding group's name in order to be able to differentiate between the groups.